# vscode-tomcat stopping issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, war

I debug war on vscode tomcat extension and it works fine. The issue is when I try to stop tomcat, it throws some error and not stop and shows always green.
[image]

java pid shows tomcat still running. When I pkill java process then vscode-tomcat goes red.

```
apache-tomcat-9.0.34 ps aux | grep java
```

snb              93854 100.0  2.1 10618536 353492   ??  R    10:41PM  49:07.67 /usr/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=localhost:8000 -classpath /Users/snb/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.34/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/snb/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.34/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/Users/snb/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/67a9c0d6ca9a41f8deff20583f3e36ec/adashen.vscode-tomcat/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.34 -Dcatalina.home=/Users/snb/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.34 -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/snb/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/67a9c0d6ca9a41f8deff20583f3e36ec/adashen.vscode-tomcat/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.34/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

How can I solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @PreDestroy annotation.

The @PreDestroy annotation is used on methods as a callback notification to signal that the instance is in the process of being removed by the container.

```
@Component
public class UserRepository {

    private DbConnection dbConnection;
    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        dbConnection.close();
    }
}
```